# matlab - figure keeps blinking when streaming webcam

Tags: matlab, streaming, webcam, figure, axes

I first created a figure to stream webcam images onto it. I then created a 3D axes on the figure while streaming from the webcam. Note that the webcam frame streaming is not set inside the 3D axes but is set outside of the 3D axes in the figure itself. The problem is that the figure keeps blinking when I stream the webcam due to the `uistack(ah,'bottom')` function. I need this function to keep the 3D axes `ah` in front of the streaming figure background `frame`.

As you can see, I am using my webcam to stream apples. You can also see that the 3D axes is in front of the background thanks to the `uistack(ah,'bottom')` function. If I didn't use this function, the 3D axes would be hidden behind the background.

[image]

```
% turn on webcam
camList = webcamlist;
cam = webcam(camList{1});

% stream webcam
while(1)
    frame = snapshot(cam);
    ah = axes('unit','normalized','position',[0 0 1 1]);
    imagesc(frame)
    drawnow
    set(ah,'handlevisibility','off','visible','off','Clipping','off')
    uistack(ah,'bottom')
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem.

You need to define two axes: (i) one for the streaming images `az` and (ii) another one for the static image `ah` **outside** of the loop. Also, place the `uistack` function **outside** since it is redundant to tell the program to keep `ah` on top of the `az` axes every loop.

```
camList = webcamlist;
cam = webcam(camList{1});

hold on
az = axes('unit','normalized','position',[0 0 1 1]);
ah = axes('unit','normalized','position',[0 0 1 1]);
uistack(ah,'top')

while(1)
    frame = snapshot(cam);
    imagesc(az,frame)
    drawnow
end
```